# Scrollviewer with dynamic height and menu below

Tags: wpf, xaml, scrollviewer

I cannot find any example how to implement a scrollviewer that contains a form, with the save/cancel buttons directly underneath and not separated at the bottom of the window [here is a simple layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40Lsd.png). I need to support resizing the window. I have many different lengths of forms, I want the scrollviewer to be as small as possible, and fill available space only if needed (if the form is larger). I don't want the buttons to always be pushed to the bottom of the window [Not like this!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUezo.png), but to hug closer to the form (in the case of a shorter form) [Something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyOjw.png).

In my grid, I have a row for the ScrollViewer, a row for the buttons, and a row to fill remaining space (if any).

I understand that by setting the row height=Auto kills the ScrollViewer. How can I implement this then? Is this even possible?

Jeff -> Here is an [image showing the window height increased](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZeQR.png). And an [image showing the window height decreased](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i14L8.png), the buttons can disappear from view, and the scrollviewer overflows so that you cannot see all of it

```
<Window x:Class="WpfAppRenderPathGeometry.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfAppRenderPathGeometry"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="500" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" x:Name="ScrollRow"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="80" x:Name="ButtonsRow"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" x:Name="SpaceRow"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="MyScroll" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
            <Grid x:Name="MyForm">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">LABEL</TextBlock>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1"></TextBox>

                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">LABEL</TextBlock>
                <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"></TextBox>

                <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0">LABEL</TextBlock>
                <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"></TextBox>

                <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0">LABEL</TextBlock>
                <TextBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1"></TextBox>

                <TextBlock Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0">LABEL</TextBlock>
                <TextBox Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1"></TextBox>

                <TextBlock Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0">LABEL</TextBlock>
                <TextBox Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1"></TextBox>

                <TextBlock Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="0">LABEL</TextBlock>
                <TextBox Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="1"></TextBox>

                <TextBlock Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="0">LABEL</TextBlock>
                <TextBox Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="1"></TextBox>

                <TextBlock Grid.Row="8" Grid.Column="0">LABEL</TextBlock>
                <TextBox Grid.Row="8" Grid.Column="1"></TextBox>

                <TextBlock Grid.Row="9" Grid.Column="0">LABEL</TextBlock>
                <TextBox Grid.Row="9" Grid.Column="1"></TextBox>

                <TextBlock Grid.Row="10" Grid.Column="0">LABEL</TextBlock>
                <TextBox Grid.Row="10" Grid.Column="1"></TextBox>

                <TextBlock Grid.Row="11" Grid.Column="0">LABEL</TextBlock>
                <TextBox Grid.Row="11" Grid.Column="1"></TextBox>
            </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1">
            <Button>CANCEL</Button>
            <Button>SAVE</Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an example, I think this will do what you want - just adjust as you need.

I adjusted again but I am not sure I understand your intent.

```
<Window
        x:Class="WpfSubDivideWindow.ScrollViewWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfSubDivideWindow"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:MyNamespace="clr-namespace:WpfSubDivideWindow"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        Title="ScrollViewWindow"
        Width="800"
        Height="350"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        >

    <Window.Resources>

        <Style x:Key="tbk.Base"
                TargetType="TextBlock"
                >
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18" />
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,12,20,12" />
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="tbx.Base"
                TargetType="TextBox"
                >
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18" />
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,12,60,12" />
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="Btn.Base"
                TargetType="Button"
                >
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18" />
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkGreen" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="20,0,0,0" />
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="36" />
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="90" />
        </Style>

    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <RowDefinition x:Name="ScrollRow" MaxHeight="{Binding ElementName=MyForm, Path=ActualHeight}" />
            <RowDefinition x:Name="ButtonsRow" Height="80" />
            <RowDefinition x:Name="SpaceRow" Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ScrollViewer x:Name="MyScroll"
                HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                >
            <Grid x:Name="MyForm"
                    Background="Moccasin"
                    >
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />

                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="160" />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <TextBlock
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        Text="INDEX"
                        Style="{StaticResource tbk.Base}"
                        />


                <TextBox
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        Style="{StaticResource tbx.Base}"
                        />

                <TextBlock
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        Text="INDEX"
                        Style="{StaticResource tbk.Base}"
                        />


                <TextBox
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        Style="{StaticResource tbx.Base}"
                        />


                <TextBlock
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        Grid.Row="2"
                        Text="INDEX"
                        Style="{StaticResource tbk.Base}"
                        />


                <TextBox
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Grid.Row="2"
                        Style="{StaticResource tbx.Base}"
                        />


                <TextBlock
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        Grid.Row="3"
                        Text="INDEX"
                        Style="{StaticResource tbk.Base}"
                        />


                <TextBox
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Grid.Row="3"
                        Style="{StaticResource tbx.Base}"
                        />


                <TextBlock
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        Grid.Row="4"
                        Text="INDEX"
                        Style="{StaticResource tbk.Base}"
                        />


                <TextBox
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Grid.Row="4"
                        Style="{StaticResource tbx.Base}"
                        />


                <TextBlock
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        Grid.Row="5"
                        Text="INDEX"
                        Style="{StaticResource tbk.Base}"
                        />


                <TextBox
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Grid.Row="5"
                        Style="{StaticResource tbx.Base}"
                        />


                <TextBlock
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        Grid.Row="6"
                        Text="INDEX"
                        Style="{StaticResource tbk.Base}"
                        />


                <TextBox
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Grid.Row="6"
                        Style="{StaticResource tbx.Base}"
                        />


                <TextBlock
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        Grid.Row="7"
                        Text="INDEX"
                        Style="{StaticResource tbk.Base}"
                        />


                <TextBox
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Grid.Row="7"
                        Style="{StaticResource tbx.Base}"
                        />

            </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer>
        <StackPanel
                Grid.Row="1"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                Orientation="Horizontal"
                >
            <Button
                    Content="Cancel"
                    Margin="0"
                    Style="{StaticResource Btn.Base}"
                    />
            <Button
                    Content="Save"
                    Style="{StaticResource Btn.Base}"
                    />

        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: I have tried this and it works, except for the fact that when you make the window larger, the form will remain at the top of the window and the cance/save buttons will move to the bottom of the window. I would like a solution where the buttons could remain 'touching' the end of the form, so a user does not have to search for the buttons

Comment: Forgive me but I do not understand what you mean by: _"touching' the end of the form, so a user does not have to search for the buttons._  Or, do you mean that the `ScrollViewer` does not change size, and, therefore the buttons do not move if the window's size is changed?  If this is what you mean, you have two choices. 1) fix the height of the `ScrollViewer`'s row or 2) fix the height of the `ScrollViewer`.

Comment: Hi, in the original post there are 3 images. Click the link that reads 'not like this!' to see how the buttons are separated from the form. Click the link that reads 'something like this' to see the buttons are actually part of the form. The buttons must always be visible, they cannot be inside the scrollviewer where the user must scroll to the bottom of the form to see the buttons (in case of a long form)

Comment: I modified the code to better match your image.  I also used styles to reduce the code length and to help insure consistency.  Let me know if this works as you are thinking.

Comment: Hi, I wish that I could insert an image of the result, but when I minimize the window the buttons disappear and the scrollviewer does not resize, it overflows from the viewable area.

Comment: yes, I will need to see an image.  I tested minimizing / restoring the window and it worked correctly.  Please edit your original post to add an image.  However, this is sounding like a new issue / question

Comment: Ok I added images to the original post

Comment: I think you want this - change `<RowDefinition x:Name="ScrollRow" Height="240" />` to read  `<RowDefinition x:Name="ScrollRow" MaxHeight="240" />`

Comment: No, this will not help. If the window is then maximized, the scrollviewer is limited to the top, it does not fill the viewable area in the window

Comment: Yes.  That matches your image noted as "Something like this" - is that image wrong?

Comment: Not exactly. In the image "Something like this" I am showing you that I want the buttons to be directly at the bottom of the form, and not at the bottom of the window. The entire form is displayed, as it is less than the available space. In your "image showing the window height increased", we are only able to see part of the form. In your image, the scrollviewer should increase it's height to acquire all available space, while leaving the buttons visible at the bottom.

Comment: Well...  Your image shows 4 rows and you say that the entire form is displayed.  However, your sample code has 12 rows which says that the whole form is not displayed.  So, do you want the window to increase in height unlimited but the scrollviewer to increase in height until the whole form is displayed?  Then if lengthened, the bottom of the form continues but the scrollviewer stops with the buttons just below the window?  When shrinking, does the scrollview keep getting shorter until it disappears but always keep the buttons visible?  Or does the window have a minimum size?

Comment: In the original comment, I said "in the case of a shorter form". This means that the form itself is dynamic, sometimes it is very long (>30 rows) and sometimes it is short (like maybe only 4 rows). This is why there were multiple images. I thought I was very clear in the original post. (1) for a small window or in the case that form is larger than window, the form can be scrolled and buttons are always visible (2) "not like this", the window is larger, but the buttons are fixed to the bottom (3) "like this" buttons appropriately stick to the bottom of the form

Comment: I have adjusted again.  I am not sure I understand your intent.  When you said form originally, I took that as the whole window and not the content within the ScrollViewer.  Try my adjustment and see what you think.

Comment: This works exactly as needed, thank you Jeff for your patience with this topic!